# Pandas Rolling Window that Skips Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas data-frame which consist of a Member Column and a SaleDate. I have engineered an extra column to represent the start of the month for each row.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Member':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
'SaleDate': ['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-02-29','2020-02-14','2020-03-31','2020-04-30','2020-02-29','2020-03-31','2020-04-30','2020-05-30','2020-06-14']})

a['SaleDate'] = a['SaleDate'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
a['Date_Month_Start'] = a['SaleDate'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
```

I have used the following to find the next transaction date per member which is working fine.

```
a['last_tx'] = a.sort_values(by=['SaleDate'], ascending= True).groupby(['Member'])['SaleDate'].shift(1)
a['next_tx'] = a.sort_values(by=['SaleDate'], ascending= True).groupby(['Member'])['SaleDate'].shift(-1)
```

What I want now is that for each line find the last and next transaction month but

```
a['last_month_tx'] = a.sort_values(by=['Date_Month_Start'], ascending= True).groupby(['Member'])['Date_Month_Start'].shift(1)
a['next_month_tx'] = a.sort_values(by=['Date_Month_Start'], ascending= True).groupby(['Member'])['Date_Month_Start'].shift(-1)
```

doesn't remove the duplicates of values in the Date_Month_Start column.

I have used the following to solve the problem but was wondering if there's a more elegant solve to this problem without creating an extra dataframe and merging it back.

```
a_month = a[['Member','Date_Month_Start']].drop_duplicates()
a_month['last_month_tx'] = a.sort_values(by=['Date_Month_Start'], ascending= True).groupby(['Member'])['Date_Month_Start'].shift(1)
a_month['next_month_tx'] = a.sort_values(by=['Date_Month_Start'], ascending= True).groupby(['Member'])['Date_Month_Start'].shift(-1)


result = pd.merge(a,a_month,how = 'left', left_on=['Member','Date_Month_Start'], right_on =['Member','Date_Month_Start'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you did it it's elegant enough. I couldn't find a way to not use `drop_duplicates`, but we can use it inside the `groupby` function, though (so you don't have to create a new variable with the dataframe).

```py
# First, sort the date values per group at once
a = a.groupby('Member').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Date_Month_Start','SaleDate'])).reset_index(drop=True)

# Then, perform the calculations by Member:
a[['last_tx','next_tx','last_month_tx','next_month_tx']] = (
    a.groupby('Member')
    .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({
        'last_tx'       : x['SaleDate'].shift(),
        'next_tx'       : x['SaleDate'].shift(-1),
        'last_month_tx' : x['Date_Month_Start'].drop_duplicates().shift().reindex(x.index).ffill(),
        'next_month_tx' : x['Date_Month_Start'].drop_duplicates().shift(-1).reindex(x.index[:-1]).ffill().reindex(x.index)
    })
))
```

Output:

```
   Member   SaleDate Date_Month_Start    last_tx    next_tx last_month_tx next_month_tx
0       A 2020-01-01       2020-01-01        NaT 2020-02-01           NaT    2020-02-01
1       A 2020-02-01       2020-02-01 2020-01-01 2020-02-29    2020-01-01    2020-03-01
2       A 2020-02-29       2020-02-01 2020-02-01 2020-02-14    2020-01-01    2020-03-01
3       A 2020-02-14       2020-02-01 2020-02-29 2020-03-31    2020-01-01    2020-03-01
4       A 2020-03-31       2020-03-01 2020-02-14 2020-04-30    2020-02-01    2020-04-01
5       A 2020-04-30       2020-04-01 2020-03-31        NaT    2020-03-01           NaT
6       B 2020-02-29       2020-02-01        NaT 2020-03-31           NaT    2020-03-01
7       B 2020-03-31       2020-03-01 2020-02-29 2020-04-30    2020-02-01    2020-04-01
8       B 2020-04-30       2020-04-01 2020-03-31 2020-05-30    2020-03-01    2020-05-01
9       B 2020-05-30       2020-05-01 2020-04-30 2020-06-14    2020-04-01    2020-06-01
10      B 2020-06-14       2020-06-01 2020-05-30        NaT    2020-05-01           NaT
```

Here, I used `reindex` to re-create the lost indexes with `sort_values`, then fill up `NaN` accordingly. Since we cannot fill all `NaN` for the next date using a forward fill (because the last date doesn't have a next date), I have reindexed it twice (the first time, I exclude the last row of the group).